# Is it possible to open an SharePoint app as Modal dialog from a Custom Action

Tags: 2013, custom-action, app

I want to create a site action menu item Custom Action which opens a Sharepoint 15 app (default.aspx) as modal dialog. is it possible? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is out of the box support for opening a dialog from custom action. Add following attributes to the CustomAction XML node --

- HostWebDialog : Set it to true if you want to open a dialog
- HostWebDialogWidth: Width of the dialog
- HostWebDialogHeight: Height of the dialog

For more information go to my blog [here](http://kiranchauhan.com/2014/08/06/create-dialog-based-custom-action-using-sharepoint-app/). Hope this would help you.

Comment: what I meant with `site action menu` was that menu contians site setting and site content, under the gear. I want to have a menu there that you can open an sharePoint app in a modal winodow. the exampel in your link is for List under EditControlBlock

Answer (score 1):

Open Elements.xml file of custom action and add following attributes in  tag.

```
        HostWebDialog="TRUE"
        HostWebDialogWidth="600"
        HostWebDialogHeight="400
```

and then in your aspx page add

```
<WebPartPages:AllowFraming ID="AllowFraming" runat="server"/>
```

For detail documentation go to this link -
[How to create custom action opens in Modal - SharePoint App](http://blog.binaryrepublik.com/2016/10/how-to-create-custom-action-to-deploy.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it through the following way:

1) Create a SharePoint page: placeHolder.aspx

2) Create an AppPart/Client WebPart for your App and place it on placeHolder.aspx

3) Open placeHolder.aspx inside the Modal Dialog

4) Open the Modal Dialog from a custom action.

Comment: Do you mean a usual Custom Action or those that came with SharePoint Apps. If it is a usual how do I can point to the app part?
and If it is a custom action app then how can I open a modal dialog. I have previously created Custom Actions which opened application pages as modal. but a usual Custom action can not be added to a SharePoint App project.